# Using functions in Magento is adding backticks to Filters with functions. Is there a good way to make these MySQL function work?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am using Magento 1, and I am trying to add a filter by `week(created_time)` with the following code:

```
$week = 37;
$weekCollection = Mage::getModel('module/modle_name')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter("week(created_time)", $week);
```

Unfortunately, backticks are added around the whole function, so I get the error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'week(created_time)' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, SUM(commission) AS `commission_total` FROM `affiliateplus_transaction` AS `main_table` WHERE (`account_id` = '1546') AND (`week(created_time)` = '37') GROUP BY week(created_time, 1)

Is there a legitimate way in Magento 1 to apply MySQL functions to column names?

Comment: In the error it is not seen but `week(created_time)` is inside of back-ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Zend_Db_Expr.
If magento encounters a Zend_Db_Expr it will just parse it to a string and don't modify it in any way.

So it will look like this:

```
$week = 37;
$weekCollection = Mage::getModel('module/modle_name')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter(new Zend_Db_Expr("week(created_time)"), $week);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an expression attribute first. This is a way of creating a virtual column based on a MySQL function.

```
$week = 37;
$weekCollection = Mage::getModel('module/modle_name')->getCollection()
            ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect( 'match_week', 'week({{created_time}})', array( 'created_time' => 'created_time' ) )
            ->addFieldToFilter( 'match_week', $week);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried your code in different variations but getting an error 

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magestore_Affiliateplus_Model_Mysql4_Transaction::addAttributeToSelect()